# Laravel Eloquent Queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need help with Eloquent. When i tried searching for `manufacturer name` it returns nothing, but if i try searching for `manufacturer` or `name`, it returns me some results.

My current table structure is:

Product:

```
 manufacturer_id, FK id on manufacturer

 model_id, FK id id on model
```

Manufacturer:

```
 id
 name
```

Model:

```
 id
 manufacturer_id, FK id on manufacturer
 name
```

My code is as such:

```
    $q = Input::get("query");
    $words = str_replace(" ", "%", $q);

    $cars = Product::whereHas('model', function ($query) use ($words) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', "%$words%");
    })->orWhereHas('manufacturer', function ($query) use ($words) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', "%$words%");
    })->get();
```

Please help me, I'm really new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
$query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $words . '%);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
$cars = Product::whereHas('model', function ($query) use ($words) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $words . '%');
    })->orWhereHas('manufacturer', function ($query) use ($words) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $words . '%');
    })->get();
```

as you're using `"%$words%"` it'll not take any value.

`"%{$words}%"` or `'%' . $words . '%'` you can use this as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Same results. If i were to type in my search bar, it works only if I type the model_name or manufacturer_name, but not both manufacturer_name and model_name together.

Comment: Can you assign some value to `$words` as static as `$words = 'php_newb'` and then check is it working? it yes then something wrong with your words variable.

Comment: Hi, it is working. I've tried a static variable value. What I'm trying to achieve here is that in my search query, let's say i'm searching for "Porsche Taycan" or something similar, it returns nothing even though "Porsche" exists in the `manufacturer` table, "Taycan" exists in the `model` table. But if i were to search for "Porsche" or "Taycan" alone, "Porsche Taycan" along with other results pop up.

Comment: Happy to hear that. It means there is no error in your code right?

Comment: No, it only works partially. I can't type both together, I can only either type one or the other in my search field

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you doing this:

```
$words = str_replace(" ", "%", $q);
```

because later on you are anyway adding "%" with `$words` variable. So do it like this:

```
$words = trim(Input::get("query"));

$cars = Product::whereHas('model', function ($query) use ($words) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', "%$words%");
})->orWhereHas('manufacturer', function ($query) use ($words) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', "%$words%");
})->get();
```

This should work for single words search. 
Now if you want to match multiple words, seperated by space, you will need to use `explode()` to actually get each word and write a `OR AND WHERE` combination to match results. OR you can use MYSQL FULL TEXT QUERY but that is outside of the scope of this question.

Please ask a separate question for that.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Yes, how might it work if I want to search multiple words separated by spaces?

Comment: As I mentioned, that is a separate question, please mark the answer accepted if it helped you and open a different thread with a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation, like this:

```
$query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $words . '%);
```

Instead this:

```
$query->where('name', 'like', "%$words%");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
$query->Where('column_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%')
```